# Internet facing servers vs production servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, web-applications

I am learning Cybersecurity.  I am confused with security of internet facing servers and production servers. What does they actually mean?

Comment: This question will likely get closed because it is not programming-related. You might have better luck asking at ServerFault. Basically, "Production" servers mean things that are running real workloads (as opposed to development or test systems). A Production system is not necessarily internet-facing. For example, an internal HR system that is used by people to manage staff, hiring, salaries, etc would be a Production system, yet it is not accessible from the Internet. IT people care a lot about Production systems, because they are the system's they're paid to keep operational.

Comment: I am trying to understand what does this have to do with Cyber Security.. Can you give it some context?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your question is very much related to Cybersecurity. Any server that is internet facing, are more viable for attacks if there are no proper security measures taken. You may have some servers, that is internal say for some scheduled tasks or cron jobs. They are not at great risk compared to internet-facing servers. A web or mobile application that is widely used globally will have a internet facing server.

Production servers facing the internet should be in a controlled environment protected by a Firewall or security groups set for the server.

Hope this adds some clarity